# Imports are not recognised after library integration

Tags: gradle, import, aar

I have a project with several modules, and I would like to add an aar dependency to one of these modules.

```
application project
 > module 1  - add new lib inside this module
 > module 2
 > app
 >.gradle
```

I added this to the gradle file of the module that I want:

```
 dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile(name:'xxxxxx-lib-xxxx', ext:'aar')
}
```

The gradle doesn't complains about nothing, but when I try to import something from the lib, the **imports are not recognised**.